# Angular ui-sref href resolve completion callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a menu with a list of links which are resolved by ui-sref

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li data-ng-repeat="var in variables">
     <a ui-sref="user.method({myparam:var.id})">nicename</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is - this takes around 5 seconds to resolve and until it is resolved, the href provided by angular is a template - which causes location error if clicked before it is replaced.

The ideal solution would be to use an `ng-click="$event.preventDefault();"` until href is fully resolved  and remove it on a callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up with a directive-usage solution

css:

```
a.disabled {
    color: #cccccc;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

html:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li data-ng-repeat="var in variables">
     <a class="lock-before-resolved disabled" ui-sref="user.method({myparam:var.id})">nicename</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

js

```
.directive('lockBeforeResolved', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'C', //check as a class
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        attrs.$observe('href',function(){
            element.toggleClass("disabled");
        });
        element.on("click", function(e) {
            if (element.hasClass("disabled")) {
                e.stopPropagation();;
                return false;
            }
        });
    },
}
})
```

Initially, when `sref` isnt yet resolved, the link stays unclickable. After resolve events, the class disabled is removed which allows clicking on a link.

Hope it helps someone